# Invalid session id when closing current tab with CodeceptJs

Tags: javascript, webdriver, codeceptjs

I am getting an `invalid session id`
error when trying to close my current tab using CodeceptJs and `I.closeCurrentTab()` and not sure how to fix this as most questions here seem to be about other frameworks, such as Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working and it seems you actually need to **switch back** to the main tab and then **close the ***other*** tabs** instead

```
When('The user switches back to the main tab', async () => {
  await I.switchTo();
  await I.closeOtherTabs();
});
```

More info [here](https://codecept.io/helpers/Protractor/#switchto)